# CSS/JavaScript Slideshow Malfunction

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress-theming

I've spent way too long trying to figure this out so I've had to resort to asking for help. It is probably a really simple fix, something to do with what the parent container's position property is set to.

The effects are being rendered, just off the top right corner of the page. I've also had to remove some of the thumbnail features to even get it to work as much as it is now. I didn't want to reformat my whole site, I only wanted this script for my portfolio (and in the future, gallery) pages.

The link in question goes to [the portfolio page of my website](http://realslickdesigns.com/portfolio/), and appears just under the head navigation. I bought the license to it ([Visio theme, seen here](http://www.kriesi.at/themedemo/?theme=avisio)), but the developer hasn't been able to offer support to my issue.

Maybe I'm getting dumber, I don't know. I appreciate the help, as always!

Comment: I assure you, it doesn't have anything to do with the .css files being linked or un-linked.

Comment: Wow, I thought this might be a simple fix. No one sees the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In poking around your site in the Chrome object inspector, the first thing I noticed is that the `aviaslider.css`, `style1.css` and `prettyPhotos.css` files all failed to load with the page.  If those have relevant CSS in them, that could explain why things aren't working.  You can see for yourself that all of these are missing:

```
http://realslickdesigns.com/portfolio/aviaslider.css
http://realslickdesigns.com/portfolio/style1.css
http://realslickdesigns.com/portfolio/prettyPhoto.css
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I was testing it further locally. I had changed and consolidated some of those files, but now they are all up there, just like the theme has them.

It might take a closer look at some of the CSS, particularly the positioning of some of the parent elements I think.